# React loop through children without ref

Tags: reactjs

So let's say I have a react component that's being rendered like this:

```
<Form />
```

In this case, inside `Form`, `this.props.children` is `undefined`.

However, inside `render`, I have the following:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <form>
       <input name='foo' />
       <input name='bar' />
    </form>
  )
}
```

It would be easy to access 'foo' and 'bar' by using the `ref` keyword. However, this is not flexible/reusable when I have a lot of "children" (that I can't access with this.props.children or `React.Children.forEach` because they're not "children")

I would like to loop through all the child components that are in render without having to give a ref for each one. (If I give a ref, I would be able to loop through `this.refs`)

Is this possible?

Comment: Is there any reason you want to loop through the inputs ?

Comment: @Harish certainly. I have `<Input>` components that I have created that have a "valid" state. I want to loop through all of them to determine if the state of the form is valid.

Comment: Have you considered centralization of the form's state or bubbling it to the host component rather than looping through the children?

Comment: @WiredPrairie yup.. Let's consider the child's state in this case. It's either valid or invalid. When it's changes state and notifies the parent, the parent still needs to know the states of all the children in order to determine whether the form can be submitted. Also, think about nested components, I would need to bubble up many levels or implement flux, which I don't think is the best way to go here. The most reusable way I think is a validatable form that can take React components tagged with a valid state. Parents recursively checks all children and determine validity.

Comment: React is designed to be one-way data flow (with events being a way for notification). So, for a parent to loop "multiple levels" through children to evaluate validity seems like it may not be the best React pattern. You don't need to implement Flux to have centralized data. You could pass an object that had some methods that could be used to indicate the validity of a component for example.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I get what you're saying and it makes sense for many other problems. (I certainly appreciate your comment too :-) )
My aim is to make my form components as reusable as possible; in your suggestion, I might have to pass this object down to all `<Input>s`. Using one-way data flow and callbacks makes this not so reusable and very spaghetti like for me and those that will reuse my components. I'm hoping to find a way to loop through a component's react children. Although react suggests one way data flow as a good pattern, they are not forcing it as the only pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Before getting to an answer, a bit of terminology clarification: Those input elements are part of the DOM for `Form`; they are not child components (at least not in Reactjs parlance).

A common solution to your problem is to convert those input elements into React Input components so that you can access them using `this.props.children`. You would have an "implementation" form that contains both the generic `Form` component and all the `Input` components. It would look something likes this

```
<MyForm>
    <GenericForm>
         <Input name='foo' />
         <Input name='bar' />
    </GenericForm>
</MyForm>
```

In this example, `GenericForm` can iterate over `this.props.children` to access the foo and the bar `Inputs`

Note that `MyForm` exists simply to encapsulate the entire form and allow you to re-use that specific form as a single component. I only included it because your example has `Form` as a single entity. If you are only using the form in a single place, you don't really need `MyForm`.

Comment: So you're suggesting to have an intermediary child which role is to only hold children? This sounds like an OK solution I think. Let me give it a shot =) As for the terminology, yes, <Form /> has no this.props.children on purpose.

Comment: What would I do if my form were to generate its children? E.g. a list of input 1, 2, 3, ... Is there a way for it to set its own children?